# If I create a function to display alert box .if I call from MainActivity.java but if I call this from SmsManager then the dialog box is not displayed

Tags: android

```
package test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class DisplayAlert extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    int t;

        public  int dis(Context activityContext, String destinationAddress)
        {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(activityContext).setTitle("SEND MESSAGE")
               .setMessage("Are you sure you want to send this msg to no ?   "+ destinationAddress)
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                { 

                            t=0;
                  }
                })
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 

                       t=1;
               }
   })
  .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
   .show();
    return t;
}
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


}
```

**The smsManager.java**

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.os.ServiceManager;
//import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.text.TextUtils;

import com.android.internal.telephony.ISms;
import com.android.internal.telephony.IccConstants;
import com.android.internal.telephony.SmsRawData;
import com.android.internal.telephony.cdma.SmsMessage;
import com.meproject2.MainActivity;

import test.DisplayAlert;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
//import com.meproject2.MainActivity;
/*
 * TODO(code review): Curious question... Why are a lot of these
 * methods not declared as static, since they do not seem to require
 * any local object state?  Presumably this cannot be changed without
 * interfering with the API...
 */


    public void sendTextMessage(
            String destinationAddress, String scAddress, String text,
            PendingIntent sentIntent, PendingIntent deliveryIntent) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(destinationAddress)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid destinationAddress");
        }

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid message body");
        }

        try {
            ISms iccISms = ISms.Stub.asInterface(ServiceManager.getService("isms"));
            if (iccISms != null) {
                iccISms.sendText(destinationAddress, scAddress, text, sentIntent, deliveryIntent);
            }
        } catch (RemoteException ex) {
            // ignore it
        }
    }

    //---------------------------My  function-----------------------------------------------------
    public void sendTextMessage1(
            final String destinationAddress, final String scAddress, final String text,
            final PendingIntent sentIntent, final PendingIntent deliveryIntent)
          {

            //MainActivity ob=new MainActivity();
             // DisplayAlert ob=new DisplayAlert();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(destinationAddress)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid destinationAddress");
        }

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid message body");
        }

                    final ISms iccISms = ISms.Stub.asInterface(ServiceManager.getService("isms"));
            if (iccISms != null) 
            {
                try
                {
                if( destinationAddress.length()<10 )
                  {

                    j=ob.dis(SmsManager.this, destinationAddress);
                      if (j==0)
                      {

                        try
                           {

                               iccISms.sendText(destinationAddress, scAddress, text, sentIntent, deliveryIntent);
                             }
                            catch (RemoteException ex) {
                     // ignore it
                             }
                       }

                  }
               else
              {
                  try
                {
                  iccISms.sendText(destinationAddress, scAddress, text, sentIntent, deliveryIntent);
                }
                 catch (RemoteException ex) {
                       // ignore it
                   }
              }
               //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------




            }

                catch(Exception e){
                    }
                }

    }


    //-------------------------------
```

**I created a function to display a dialog box .  If I CALL THE FUNCTION FROM MainActivity.java then the  dialog box is displayed but if I call this from SmsManager then the dialog box is not displayed.**

Answer (score 0):

its because you are referring variable "t" which is in MainActivity,which may not be alive when you call dialog from smsManager

declare "t" inside dialog function